# How to make Windows inserting a "λ" after pressing Alt-Gr-l?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

In the same way as Alt-Gr-m inserts a µ or Alt-Gr-e inserts a € I would like Alt-Gr-l to insert a λ. How can this be configured in Windows 7?

Comment: You could try the [Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) , although I haven’t tried myself. Which keyboard layout are you using at the moment?

Comment: @DanielB german

Comment: I see. Although it’s not exactly helping the question, I recommend [this layout](http://www.europatastatur.de/). Again: Doesn’t do what you want, is very cool nonetheless.

Comment: @DanielB Maybe this helps. I will try it. The problem with Windows is, that Alt-Gr-l does not produce any character. If it would produce `ł` which is also the default on Linux I could map it in Emacs `(global-set-key (kbd "ł") "λ")`.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + 955

This works in MS Word, but it is not working in notepad or anywhere else for whatever strange reason it creates this weird sign "╗"

http://mathinword.com/shortcut-keys-alt-codes-for-greek-letters/

Comment: Alt-Gr-l was the key I want to press.

Comment: Have a look at Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/goglobal/bb964665.aspx, You can map any key as you want it, then install the new layout in windows and use it. I am not sure about the keyboard combinations though have a look

Comment: I will try it. Looks promising.